# ¿Cómo actualizar una web progresiva (PWA) en forma correcta, para que el usuario detecte los cambios?

Tags: javascript, pwa, service-workers

Estoy trabajando con una muy simple web progresiva para móviles ( la aplicación es muy simple y no da para hacer una app ). Como corresponde, esta web para móviles instala un Service Workers (sw.js) para cachear los elementos offline y su correspondiente `manifest.json`.  Al comienzo del Service Workers indique lo siguiente:

```
var cacheName = 'v1.0.3.0:static';
```

En lo que creía que cada vez que cambiara el valor de la versión tal como indica el post de [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/?hl=es), el usuario recibiría la nueva actualización, pero esto no funciona. El usuario mantiene su antigua versión sin recibir los cambios y la única forma, hasta el momento, es que los usuarios eliminen el historial desde su móvil (y en algunos casos re instalen al PWA).

¿ Existe alguna forma de  hacer esto en forma automática o notificar al usuario ( sin usar notificaciones push) de los nuevos cambios? Adjunto mi sw.js por si sirve para el análisis.

```
var cacheName = 'v1.0.3.0:static';

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {   
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                'https://www.......com',
                'https://www.......com/js/app.js',
                ....
                ....

            ]).then(function() {
                self.skipWaiting();
            });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {   
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {              
                return response;
            }          
            return fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta borrar las versiones viejas del cache al momento de actualizarse el service worker.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(function(names) {
        return Promise.all(
            names.filter(function(name) {
                return name !== cacheName;
            }).map(function(name) {
                return caches.delete(name);
            })
        );
    }).then(function() {
        return self.clients.claim();
    }));
});
```

Lo que hace este código es ejecutar una función al momento que el nuevo service worker pasa a estar activo. Entonces, obtiene todos los nombres de los caches creados y los itera para eliminar todos los que no se llamen igual que la constante "cacheName".

**Nota:** Para ver los cambios es necesario volver a cargar la página.

Comment: Consulta ¿este código se pone en vez de self.addEventListener('fetch'... o después de self.addEventListener('fetch'... ?

Comment: @EduardoMunizaga Va después. En el evento fetch lo que haces es interceptar las peticiones que hace tu sitio por HTTP y determinar si responde con las datos que hay en caché o los descarga del servidor.